# Determine the nature of the isolated singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} Log(1+z) $
Here's what I did so far:
Because Log is not continuous along the negative real axis,
hence, $z = -1$ is not an isolated singularity. The only isolated singularity is $z = 0$.
$ z f(z) = Log(1+z) \rightarrow 0$  as $z \rightarrow 0$
so, it must not be a simple pole.
Then it must be either removable or essential singularity, the answer given says it is a removable singularity. 
Suppose it is true, then $\frac{1}{z} Log(1+z) \not\to 0$ as $z \rightarrow 0$, but how?

Comment: How can 0 be "isolated" if the function is not continuous along the negative real axis?

Comment: What does "log is not continuous along the negative axis" mean?? Do you mean that you are **choosing** the branch of the logarithm that takes away the non-positive real axis? Because you could as well take off the non-negative real axis, say...or the non-negative imaginary axis, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever branch you choose for the logaritm, **your** function, which is *not* the complex logarithm but rather $\;\frac1z\log(1+z)\;$, is defined for example in $\;|z|<\frac12\;$ and thus zero is a removable singularity since

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\log(1+z)}z=1$$

for example using l'Hospital or Taylor series.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty in my reply. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @user_of_math Thank you.